# How do I get more Berserk potions

Tags: candy-box

So, I know how to open up the console when pressing f12, but I'm not entirely sure how to give myself more potions, ie berserk potions. Anyone tell me how please? :D

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are two main methods.

**Legitimate**:

The only way to legitimately get more berserk potions is by using the wishing well, or by going to the Swampy Swamp, and answering several of the Swampy Swamp Frog's questions correctly. Though, I believe these can be utilized only once.

**Illegitimate**:

Of course, you could also skip all of that by just using the Javascript development console, as follows:

> newPotionNum = 10; // Insert the new number of berserk potions that you desire here.
>
> potions.setPotionNbrOwned(potions.list.berserk, newPotionNum);
>
> potions.updateOnPage();